# How Can I Flip the cards in (David walsh CSS flip trick) on click?

Tags: javascript, css

I have implemented a good functional Flip-card using this article's [David walsh CSS Flip](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) technique but I want to make the flip on a javascript event rather than on a CSS hover , **please any help ?**

Comment: The short answer is "yes"...but where's your code? What have you tried?

Comment: @rnevius here it is ,http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: I did the exact horizontal flip , but I need it to work on a Javascript event

Comment: You should provide all necessary code in the question itself. Links break or become unavailable. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the demo for the [page you linked to](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php) you will see the code to do this

```
<button onclick="document.querySelector('#flip-toggle')
.classList.toggle('hover');" class="sexyButton">Toggle Flip</button>
```

Comment: thanks , but how do I select what to flip ?

Comment: @YazanRawashdeh it sounds like you need to go learn javascript.

Comment: @animatedgif sorry ,  I mean what class to select ??